# Bootstrap TokenInput Cancel all previous requests

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-typeahead

Could someone please let me know how to cancel previous ajax request when typing in the token? I am facing problem with multiple ajax requests and my server is hanging due to that.

```
            $('#Searchinput').tokenInput(getMyRestServer, {
            theme: "facebook",
            queryParam : "param",
            preventDuplicates: true,
            tokenDelimiter: "|",
            minChars: 5,
            hintText: "Type your search criteria here",
            noResultsText: "No Results found. Please refine your search...",
            searchingText: "Fetching results ...please wait...",
            allowCustomEntry: true});
```